# Colocar um balão em cima do input[type=range]

Tags: jquery, html, css, input, slider

Estou  gerando um form a partir de um php, ele gera um html igual a esse:

```
<div class="mf_slider">
  <div class="mf_slider_label">Você tem cabelos brancos?</div>
  <div class="tooltip">
    <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
    <div class="tooltip-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="3" value=0 step="0.1">
  <div class="mf_slider_content">
    <input class="mf_option" type="hidden" name="mf[gray_hair#slider][]" id="id_0" value="Não">
    <input class="mf_option" type="hidden" name="mf[gray_hair#slider][]" id="id_1" value="Um Pouco">
    <input class="mf_option" type="hidden" name="mf[gray_hair#slider][]" id="id_2" value="Médio">
    <input class="mf_option" type="hidden" name="mf[gray_hair#slider][]" id="id_3" value="Muito">
  </div>
</div>
```

O que quero fazer é que em cima do botão do range, apareça o `value` segundo os `id` dos `input` dentro `div.class="mf_slider_content"`.

Para ajudar estou colocando esse [codeopen](http://codepen.io/MarciusMcflay/pen/RaKvye). Se alguém souber como fazer isso.

**UPDATE**

Bom consegui fazer, mas o balão não aponta certinho para o botão do range ele da uma variada. Se alguém conseguir arrumar isso para mim agradeço imensamente.

Comment: interessante...não sabia que existia o atributo `label` em inputs.

Comment: não tem o atributo por padrão eu que acrescentei.

Comment: voce pode usar do bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#static-tooltip ou verificar mais detalhes na API do Slider